# Dozer: Map from Object to a specific class with wildcards

Tags: java, dozer

I'm trying to implement some simple patch-style capability that would allow me to take an arbitrary object and map the similarly named fields on to my object. This works great if I don't want to configure anything, but if I want to exclude some fields, Dozer only maps fields I specify (essentially, wildcard gets set to false). Is there any way to accomplish what I'm attempting?

Here's the question in code:

```
public class Update {
    String a;
    String b;
    // constructor, getters, and setters omitted
}

public class Destination {
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
    // constructor, getters, and setters omitted
}
```

I want to prevent people from specifying b. Using dozer's java configuration:

```
BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        mapping(Object.class, Destination.class,
                TypeMappingOptions.oneWay(),
                TypeMappingOptions.wildcard(true),
                TypeMappingOptions.mapId("Any-To-Destinaion"))
            .exclude("b");
    }

};

final DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
mapper.addMapping(builder);
```

So I should be able to call this:

```
Update u = new Update("uA", "uB");
Destination d = new Destination("dA", "dB", "dC");

mapper.map(u, d, "Any-To-Destination");

// these should all print true
System.out.println("a: " + d.getA().equals("uA"));
System.out.println("b: " + d.getB().equals("dB"));
System.out.println("c: " + d.getB().equals("dC"));
```

Output is:

```
a: false
b: true
c: true
```

Anyway to make this work?

Comment: Why do you expect the first one to be true ? With wildcard(true), it maps the "a" field...

Comment: If you notice the equals() call, it is expecting the value to be mapped, but it isn't being mapped. Notice it is checking equality against the update value and not the original destination object value.

Comment: Ok. Yes that's strange, it works if you do `mapping(Update.class, ...` but not for `mapping(Object.class, ...`

Comment: Isn't there a typo ("Any-To-Destinaion" vs. "Any-To-Destination")? Could that be the reason? Unless that happened only when writing up the question...